# Can I pass multiple args (patterns) for Javascript's replace()? If not, any good alternative?

Tags: javascript

I'm taking the following ex URL https://support.dev.mysite.com/batch/ and removing everything, but the environment (eg dev). The below code works fine.

```
var env = endPoint.replace("https://support.", "\n");
var envClean = env.replace(".mysite.com/batch/", "\n");
```

I don't like repeating myself. I would like to look for both patterns in the string and remove them all at once. MDN has a good breakdown of replace() here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace but it doesn't mention anything about multiple arguments.

I've tried this:

```
var env = endPoint.replace("https://support." && ".mysite.com/batch/", "\n");
```

but it just parses the second arg and disregards the first.

Does anyone have a cleaner way of doing this? I'm assuming I can search for multiple patterns via REGEX, any REGEX masters out there care to help?

Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regular expressions for this:

```
var environment  = 'https://support.dev.mysite.com/batch/'
    .replace(/^https:\/\/support\.|\.mysite\.com\/batch\/$/g, '');
```

Answer (score 1):

You could chain your method:

```
var envClean = endPoint.replace("https://support.", "\n").replace(".mysite.com/batch/", "\n");
```

Or you could use regex:

```
var envClean = endPoint.replace(/https:\/\/support\.|\.mysite\.com\/batch\//, "\n");
```

**And there is another solution** to get `dev`:

```
var envClean = endPoint.match(/^https:\/\/support\.([^.]*)\.mysite\.com\/batch\/$/)[1];
```

Comment: thanks for the input! For the replace w/ regex option it needed the global flag to accept multiple patterns.

Answer (score 1):

For this specific URL pattern, why not make it really simple and use `.split()`:

```
var url = 'https://support.dev.mysite.com/batch/';

var name = url.split('.')[1];
```

If I were using a regular expression, I would probably do it this way:

```
var match = url.match( /support\.(.*)\.mysite.com/ );
var name = match && match[1];
```

Note that you don't have to worry about the entire URL this way, only enough to do the match.

If you *know* that the URL will match, you can simplify that to:

```
var name = url.match( /support\.(.*)\.mysite.com/ )[1];
```

Comment: great answer. qwertymk was the first to give me a solid, simple answer, so I marked it correct. It should be noted that your url.match solution is by far the shortest and works great. Thanks!